# How do I refresh an existing object using SQLite.NET?

Tags: c#, sqlite.net

I'm using SQLite.NET and the SQLite.NET extensions to represent objects coming from a Rest API.  This is my workflow:

- Create an object locally
- Save it to the DB.
- On a background thread:

  - Get a copy of the object
  - POST it to the server
  - Update the object with what comes back
  - Save this copy of the object back to the DB
- Get notified that my object has updated.

At this point, what I want is to refresh my copy of my object with the saved data from the DB.  I *do not* want to throw my object away and create a new one.  Calling `GetChildren` refreshes the children, but it isn't refreshing the properties of the object itself.

How do I refresh an existing object using SQLite.NET?

Answer (score 0):

Very much a late answer, but this capability does not exist within SQLite.Net's API. I'm sure you've already done the obvious (pull the record, get the non-relationship properties, and copy them over).